# Autolayout iPhone 6 doesn't work

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout

I developed an app for iOS, this app should work for iPhone 4s, iPhone 5, iPhone 5c, iPhone 5s, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+. I read the apple documentations and I found that I've to design only a Storyboard in which I use auto layout and size class.
I designed the user interface with Storyboard and I set all constraints, but when I run it on my iPhone 6 it shows me the user interface not optimized for the display of my iPhone 6. Here's a sample:

[image]

As you can see it shows me the view with big operator log, big clock, big battery indicator and big keyboard.
Why it doesn't work?
Should I add the splash screen for Retina 4.7 and Retina 5.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a "launch screen file" which is a XIB or Storyboard showing the screen that is shown while launching.